# How to select values when there is an specific gap between that and the last record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, gaps-and-islands

I am creating a query that would let me select values when there is a gap of 10 between it and the last record in SQL Server.

Let's say there is a sensor in a freezer, the sensor uploads the freezer temperature every 5 minutes, I am trying to create a query that would let me get all records when temperatura dropped 2°F or more after the last record.

Here is an example of the table:

```
Value | Timestamp
------+------------------------
  10   2018-04-25 17:11:00.000 
  11   2018-04-25 17:16:00.000
  12   2018-04-25 17:21:00.000
  11   2018-04-25 17:26:00.000
  9    2018-04-25 17:31:00.000 <<<<<<<<<<<< Dropped 2°F
  10   2018-04-25 17:36:00.000 
  12   2018-04-25 17:41:00.000 
  9    2018-04-25 17:46:00.000 <<<<<<<<<<<< Dropped more than 2°F
```

Then my desired result of the query if I want it to return values from 2018-04-25 would be:

```
Times_Dropped_2
     2
```

Comment: This is a [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem.  What version of SQL Server?  Remedies highly depend on what analysis/windowing functions are available.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i am using MS SQL SERVER 2016

Comment: By "last record" you mean "immediately previous record" (as opposed to "final record by some criterion") correct?

Comment: Exacty, i want to know how many times it dropped 2°F or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to previous answer

```
 select count(*) from (SELECT value,
           Timestamp,
           value- LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS value_diff
    FROM   table)a
    where value_diff>=2
```

Comment: Thanks

I tried to approach to the solution using LAG but what is the 1,0 after value used for?

Comment: 1 is the number of rows you are looking back and 0 is the default(what to do when there's no value like on the first row)

Comment: I applied that to my query but it seems it is only taking all records whose value is equal or less than 2 rather than those records whose value is at least 2°F less than the previous record

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT value,
       Timestamp,
       value- LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS value_diff
FROM   table;
```

This lists the diff from previous entry , u can fetch ur req detail from this

Comment: I applied that with where 'value_diff>=2' to my query but it seems it is only taking all records whose value is equal or less than 2 rather than those records whose value is at least 2°F less than the previous record

Comment: can you post complete query  u r trying

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE value_diff >= Temp_Value + 10
```

This was the missing line, thanks